# Premature Action on Creating a Button

Tags: python, tkinter

The problem I am experiencing is that when I want to create a button which is supposed to do a certain action on being pressed, the action happens right away when the program starts.  In clearer terms, I have an `os.system("sudo python /home/pi/module2.py")` in a function. This is what the function might look like (oh, yeah, I imported os, and tkinter as tk):

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    button = tk.Button(self,
        text="Addition",
        command=os.system("sudo python /home/pi/module2.py")
```

What happens with this is that the `os.system` function is run before anything else starts, because it is in a function at the top of the file, and I call on the functions at the bottom of the file. So, even though the `os.system` is in a function, it still runs when it shouldn't. Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I boiled down your question to the core of the problem.  This way it has a better chance of helping others because they might have the same problem as you but would never find it with your lengthy introduction and misleading title.  Please don't be upset :)  It's just meant to improve StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function to `command=` which will do what you want.  In your solution you pass to `command=` the *result* of calling such a function, hence it is performed prematurely.

A typical way of coding this would be:

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):

    def call_module2(*args, **kwargs):  # accept all possible arguments
        os.system("sudo python /home/pi/module2.py")

    button = tk.Button(self,
        text="Addition",
        command=call_module2)
```

Or, if you prefer to use anonymous functions via `lambda`:

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    button = tk.Button(self,
        text="Addition",
        command=lambda *args, **kwargs:
            os.system("sudo python /home/pi/module2.py"))
```

Comment: ok. By any means, I need to show another frame as well as use the os.system. I've used lambda for showing the second frame.

Comment: Ohk nvm. Worked it out.